# How to compare a datetime value to an int

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

For a homework assignment I have been tasked with creating a game and have chosen to do a reaction time based "quick-draw" style game. I am currently using datetime to find the reaction time of the player but I can't seem to figure out how to get the `datetime` values to be compared with an int in an if statement to determine a winner.

I've already tried using time functions and parsing but can't seem to get it to work.

```
def playGameL1():
    drawTime = random.randint(3,7)
    print("You and the outlaw have lined up back to back and begin")
    print("taking 10 paces away from eachother...")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("The bystander who is conducting the quickdraw battle yells:")
    print("'Ready!'")
    time.sleep(drawTime)
    print("'DRAW!'")
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    draw = input()
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    reactionTime = (end-start)
    print ("Your reaction time was: ", reactionTime)

    if reactionTime<3:
        print("BANG!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You drew first and won the draw!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("The next outlaw approaches...")
        playGameL2()
    else:
        print("BANG!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The outlaw drew first and you lost!")
        time.sleep(2)
        gameLoss()
```

I would like it to determine the winner and move on to either the next level or to my gameLoss output but I am receiving errors.

I believe the program is having trouble calling other functions because of it's current inability to compare the `datetime` values to the int, but I'm not really sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reactionTime = (end-start).total_seconds()
```

Will give you the amount of seconds between the two datetimes as a `float`.

Comment: still giving me an error regarding the ability to compare the datetime value with the int

Comment: Works perfectly for me. You aren't comparing a `datetime` with an `int` anymore. If `reactionTime` is still a `dateTime`, you haven't adjusted your solution.

Comment: Yep, i fixed it and it works flawlessly for me now! Appreciate it man!